# print all matches in a string python

Tags: python, regex, text-parsing

i want to print all matches in a specific variable

code :

```
import re
regex = r"https?:\/\/?www[.]?telegram|t\.me\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\/?$"
data="https://t.me/cronosapesd fdsfdsfds https://t.me/osapesdd fd"
matches = re.findall(regex, data)
print(matches)
```

This currently outputs `[]`. I want the script to show "https://t.me/cronosapesd" and "https://t.me/osapesdd" only in a list

thanks !

Comment: See `https?://?(?:(?:www\.)?telegram|t\.me/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/?)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RIo9dg/1).

Answer (score 0):

The core of your regex `t|telegram` is not bound to a group, so it does not work as you expect, same for the `$` at the end.

This one should work better: `https?://(?:www\.)?t(?:elegram)?.me/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/?`.

It starts same as yours, matches `http` or `https`, then `www.` maybe, then `t` and maybe `elegram`, then `.me` and the end of the url.

```py
import re
regex = r"https?://(?:www\.)?t(?:elegram)?.me/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*/?"
data="https://t.me/cronosapesd fdsfdsfds https://t.me/osapesdd fd"
matches = re.findall(regex, data)
print(matches)
```

And a demo with all the versions: https://regex101.com/r/LibrFn/1

Comment: Note that the necessity for using *non-capturing* groups `(?:...)` is a quirk of [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall). Were you to use e.g. `re.finditer()`, you could use standard groups `(...)`.

Comment: I was not aware of this. I'd still use *non-capturing* groups, even if they make the regex slightly more complicated to read, since we are not in fact capturing those groups.